# Confusion on AtomicReference getAndUpdate

Tags: java

I'm a bit confused about how AtomicReference `getAndUpdate` guarantees atomicity. Consider the following examples

example 1

```
AtomicReference<Set<String>> set = new AtomicReference<>(new HashSet<>());
set.getAndUpdate(current -> {
    Set<String> updated = new HashSet<>();
    updated.add("test");
    return updated;
});
```

example 2

```
AtomicReference<Set<String>> set = new AtomicReference<>(new HashSet<>());
set.getAndUpdate(current -> {
    current.add("test");
    return current;
});
```

In example 2, the set will be modified in the callback of the `getAndUpdate`. If multiple threads try to access this function at the same time, will they see the modified state or `getAndUpdate` prevents this by cloning the original set when passing it to the callback so that the modification happens in one thread will not be seen in other threads? If example 2 does not guarantee atomicity, why would `getAndUpdate` allow us to write this code?

example 1 will guarantee the atomicity since the modification happens on a new set. But how it defers from below?

```
AtomicReference<Set<String>> set = new AtomicReference<>(new HashSet<>());
Set<String> updated = new HashSet<>();
updated.add("test");
set.set(updated);
```

Comment: Example 2 has no thread safety at all.  Your below example has no difference from Example 1, either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In example 2, the set will be modified in the callback of the getAndUpdate. If multiple threads try to access this function at the same time, will they see the modified state or getAndUpdate prevents this by cloning the original set when passing it to the callback so that the modification happens in one thread will not be seen in other threads?

There's nothing preventing the modification to the set from being seen by multiple threads. Only the change to the reference is atomic, not changes to whatever the reference refers to.

> If example 2 does not guarantee atomicity, why would getAndUpdate allow us to write this code?

Because it can't stop you. The compiler isn't smart enough to know that example 2 is broken code.

To minimize the risk of accidentally / unsafely modifying shared state, make sure the things stored in an atomic reference are immutable, or at least unmodifiable:

```java
AtomicReference<Set<String>> set = new AtomicReference<>(Collections.emptySet());

set.getAndUpdate(current -> {
  Set<String> updated = new HashSet<>();
  updated.add("test");
  return Collections.unmodifiableSet(updated);
});

// or if you're on Java 9+ 
set.getAndUpdate(current -> {
  return Set.of("test");
}
```

> example 1 will guarantee the atomicity since the modification happens on a new set. But how it defers from [AtomicReference.set()]?

Your Example 1 uses `AtomicReference.getAndUpdate` which returns the previous value, and lets you generate the new value based on the previous value. If you don't need to know what the previous value was, you can just call `AtomicReference.set`.